# If statement based on header location

Tags: php, header, conditional-operator

I am trying to use `include_once` based on whether or not a certain page is being displayed.

Here is what I am using to try to accomplish this:

```
if ( header('Location: inbox.php'){
    include_once('_class/message_core.php');
}
```

Assuming that all of the files are in the right location, is there any reason that this wouldn't work?

Comment: That is not how the header() function works. header() doesn't *retrieve* headers from the request, it *sends* headers, so you are effectively telling the script to redirect the user.

Comment: Additionally, `Location:` is a response header, not a request header.  The server sends it to the client, not the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === 'inbox.php') {
    include_once '_class/message_core.php';
}
```

`$_SERVER` is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. You can read more about it in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

`header()` is used to set response headers, i.e. `header('Location: inbox.php')` will actually redirect the user!

Also you're missing an end bracket in your code on the same line as the `if`